# Extended call-syntax: Passing parameters

Tags: python

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def getColumn(self, name, type, **args):
```

Now I would like to have a function

```
def getColumns(self, columns)
```

where I can pass a tuple that contains a tuple, where each entry in that tuple represents the
arguments to be passed go getColumn. However, I'd like not to have to use named parameters for the name and type.

So I'd like not to have to use it like this:

```
def getColumns(self, columns):
    columns = [self.getColumn(**data) for data in columns]

column_data = ( {'name' : 'myName', 'type' : 'myType', 'other' : 'myOther'},
    {'name' : 'myName2', 'type' : 'myType2', 'other' : 'myOther2'})
```

How do I get rid of the `'name':`  and `'type':`?

Comment: It is idiomatic to use `*args` for the positional arguments and `**kw` or `**kwargs` for the keyword arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
column_data = (('myName', 'myType', {'other': 'myOther'}),
               ('myName2', 'myType2', {'other2': 'myOther2'}))

def getColumn(self,name,type,**rest):
    pass

def getColumns(self,columns):
    return [self.getColumn(name, type, **rest) for name, type, rest in columns]
```

You don't have to unpack - if you remove ** before `rest`in both places the function will take a dictionary.

If you simply don't want to give names to arguments, use *args instead of **kwargs as gnibbler suggested.

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Yes, I do need named parameters^^
Now there wouldn't be any option to get rid of {} if there are no named arguments, would there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @phant0m: A very ugly way is `return [getColumn(t[0],t[1],**(t[2] if len(t)>2 else {})) for t in columns]`. It's better to leave those {} IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getColumns(self, columns):
    columns = [self.getColumn(*data) for data in columns]

column_data = (('myName', 'myType', 'myOther'), 
               ('myName2', 'myType2', 'myOther2'))
```